# with python is it possible to modify and possibly add a new line in a csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I would like to update a value of a cell in a row based on a dictionary that is gradually updated, if it is different I would like to add a new row which will then change until I find a new value.

for now my csv is empty, it has only the header

```
my csv
j      , date,      value1, value2, value3, ...
```

what I would is like this

```
my csv  
j      , date,      value1, value2, value3, ...  
string,  2020/12/26,    0,        0,       1, ...

my_dict = {'date': 2020/12/26, 'value1': 1, 'value2':0, 'value3':1, ...}
```

if the date is the same I would like to get this

```
my csv  
j      , date,      value1, value2, value3, ... 
string,  2020/12/26,    1,        0,      2, ...
```

or if the date is different, for example in such a situation:

```
my_dict = {'date': 2020/12/25, 'value1': 0, 'value2':0, 'value3':1, ...}
```

I would like my output to be this

```
my csv  
j      , date,      value1, value2, value3,  ...
string,  2020/12/26,    1,        0,       2, ...
string,  2020/12/25,    0,        0,       1, ...
```

will continue over the course of the days and the same situation should be repeated for December 25th, until December 24th and so on

Comment: please format you sample data by code block .

Comment: Would you be able to clarify where the `my_dict` dictionaries come from? Do you have a list with different dictionaries? Writing a csv in python is easy, but continuously trying to change existing lines in a csv is not that practical (csv files are not data bases where you can simply update a record). It would be easier to organise all the information you want in a data-structure in Python in your script (e.g. a dictionary with your date as the key) and then write the csv once at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. On writing the file, just add \n for a new line.

You would do this based on a condition by evaluating the date. This can be done using a comparison between your date and the date in your csv.